# Convert Dockerfile to Kubernetes yaml

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile

I have 2 line code in Dockerfile like below:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/dockerstartup/dockerstartup.sh"]
CMD ["--wait"]
```

Below is my code converted in Kubernetes yaml:

```
command: ["/dockerstartup/dockerstartup.sh"]
args: ["--wait"]
```

Is it correct?
Suggestion please.

Comment: Seems good. To check only the syntax you can add the `--dry-run`-flag to `kubectl apply`.

Comment: It cannot execute, I got the error when I create the pod.

Comment: Which error? We need some details to help you.

Comment: It works. Maybe I forgot some the path :). Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Bui Huy Could you add your solution as an answer and mark it as approved? It will make your solution more visible if anyone will be searching for similar issues

Comment: You generally wouldn't "convert" this at all: you'd just reference the built `image:` in your pod spec, and Kubernetes would run the default command there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod) docs:

> The command and arguments that you define in the configuration file
>   override the default command and arguments provided by the container
>   image.

[This](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) table summarizes the field names used by Docker and Kubernetes:

```
| Docker field name | K8s field name |
|------------------:|:--------------:|
|    ENTRYPOINT     |     command    |
|       CMD         |      args      |
```

**So, for your example you should use the following:**

**Docker:**

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/dockerstartup/dockerstartup.sh"]
CMD ["--wait"]
```

**Kubernetes:**

```
command: ["/dockerstartup/vnc_startup.sh"]
args: ["--wait"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the code below:

```
command: ["/dockerstartup/dockerstartup.sh"]
args: ["--wait"]
```

I missed some the file in script `dockerstartup.sh`, so I got the error.